# updating tensorflow causes displaying weird characters

Tags: python, tensorflow

I used to have 1.0.0 version tensorflow, and due to syntax issues, I reverted back to 0.8.0 and suddenly when I run my code, matrices are displayed like this:

```
 ÄÄ 0.  0.  0. ...,0.  0.  0.Å
 Ä 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.Å
 Ä 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  1.  0.Å
 ..., 
 Ä 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.Å
 Ä 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.Å
 Ä 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.ÅÅ
```

Å's are supposed to be square brackets.

It was fine before I reverted. Other than this, everything else seems fine, and the program executes correctly.

Comment: What code are you running? This sounds like an issue with the local configuration in your shell or terminal, but it's difficult to tell without more details.

Comment: Looks like an encoding issue.